# Custom Attribute doesn't accept non constant values .NET

Tags: c#, .net

In .NET I am basically wanting to have access to config values from my application to perform some security checks.  I have attempted to create a configuration object and make it available in my controllers.  When I try to use a property from that object as a parameter in the attribute I receive the error message:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, 'typeof()' expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type
```

Example code of what I have and would like to work in some way with modifications here:

```
  ===================================================================
  Controller
  ===================================================================

    public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger, Config config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
    }
    
    [HttpGet("/MyThings")]
    [CustomAuthorize(_config.configString)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Get(long d)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Info ...");
        try
        {
            .................

  ===================================================================
  Attribute
  ===================================================================

  public class CustomAuthorize : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
  {

    public string _securityString;

    public JWTAuthorizeAttribute(string securityString)
    {
        _securityString = securityString;
        ........
```

Can anyone help suggest a way to get strings I read from a config object into a custom attribute?  Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: _"Can anyone help suggest a way to get strings I read from a config object into a custom attribute?"_ - you can't, and you appear to misunderstand how to use attributes for authorization in ASP.NET. Are you familiar with authX Policy vs. Role vs. Assertions?

Comment: I'm not - the way we want things set up is for a JWT to be in a cookie in requests to the back end and for the custom attribute to have things like the private key in it to verify the token is valid.  We started with middleware but want be able to specifically target certain methods so it seemed like custom attribute was the way to go.

Comment: You _really_ shouldn't be using a shared private-key for JWTs - why aren't you using asymmetric signatures like RS256 or ES256? And you don't need a custom attribute: validating the JWT signature is done automatically by the `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` step. Even so, validating/verifying a JWT is _not_ an authorization check (it's an authentication check). Just follow this guide instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

Comment: I think the thing that made me think there could be a problem with that was that the JWT is in a cookie not a header.  Have to run an errand, will look at this when I get back, thank you!

Comment: The JWT will not be exposed as a raw cookie, btw (and if you are... you must stop doing that immediately): in ASP.NET Core MVC any JWT you _receive_ from an IdP will typically be stored within the `IAuthenticationTicket` which represents data stored within the ASP.NET Core cookie as an opaque blob - rather than a raw cookie).

Comment: The way things are working now the cookie is being sent to the backend on requests after the user logs in and the middleware receives the cookie on every request. Code setting the cookie here => :
            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = true,
                SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
                Expires = expiration
            };
            Response.Cookies.Append("access-token", Jwt, cookieOptions);

Comment: **That's horribly insecure!** - you must never expose raw JWTs like that... yikes. (Whereas if you just used ASP.NET Core's built-in token management features, it would store it _securely_ for you: ): `services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer()` has an option: `SaveToken = true` which handles all this for you.

Comment: Even with the HttpOnly, Secure, and SameSite?  I'll look at JwtBearer.  Your concern is that you can open up the browser and look at the JWT, correct?

Comment: Right - JWTs must never be directly exposed: as bearer-tokens (just like Bearer-Bonds) they're _massive liabilities_ and relying on browser-based security (like Cookies' `HttpOnly`, `Secure`, etc) is very weak security. E.g.: a malicious non-browser-based client can trivially pose as a browser and then get the JWT to make its own bad requests.

Comment: ASP.NET Core comes with its built-in `DataProtection` service for storing data on remote-clients via encrypted-cookies, but as I said above, [you _should_ be using `AuthenticationTicket` here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationticket).